# How To detect a number inputed from a number in array

Tags: c#-4.0

i have it generate a 4 diget random number and save it into diffrent arrays then trying to let the user try and guess the number

Generate a random four digit number. The player has to keep inputting four digit numbers until they guess the randomly generated number. After each unsuccessful try it should say how many numbers they got correct, but not which position they got right. At the end of the game should congratulate the user and say how many tries it took.
this is the breif im trying to follow

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace _4_Number_Guess_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] RanNums = new int[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Random ran = new Random();
                RanNums[i] = ran.Next(1, 9);

                Thread.Sleep(11);
            }

            int[] Input = new int[4];

            bool guess = false;

            while (guess == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input a 4 digit number: ");
                Console.

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: im trying to detect the 4 number input by a user. but it is stored in a string and im trying to detect if he inputed the exact number henrated in the array.

Comment: Haven't looked at the rest of the code yet, but this line `Random ran = new Random();` should be OUTSIDE of the loop, up above.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` returns a string.  You should capture what the user typed in so you can analyze it.  Do that by declaring a variable of type string and setting it equal to `Console.ReadLine();`.